# Question about the definition of projecting concepts in learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am self-studying in the area of query learning and having a difficulty in understanding the definition of closed under projection for concept classes discussed in several papers (for example, [here](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~bshouty/MyPapers/Learning%20with%20errors%20in%20answers%20to%20membership%20queries/MQ-ERROR.pdf) (page 2), [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.8.8103&rep=rep1&type=pdf) page 18 and [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hila/cs4252_project.pdf) page 8) with regard to learning from membership queries in Query learning.

I have a set of elements X. Each concept is a subset of X and the concept class C is a set of concepts. For example the following is a concept class over $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\}$ with three concepts $f_1$,$f_2$ and $f_3$ represent respectively the sets $\{x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ $\{x_1,x_5\}$ and $\{x_1,x_2,x_4\}$.

```
      x1|x2|x3|x4|x5
  f1  0 |1 |1 |1 |0
  f2  1 |0 |0 |0 |1
  f3  1 |1 |0 |1 |0
```

The definition is different from restricting boolean functions to a specific range $A\subseteq X$ and can be stated as follows :

> $C$ is a set of boolean functions $\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}$. A partial assignment $p$ is $(p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n)$ where $p_i\in\{0,1,*\}$. $C$ is closed under projection if for every concept $f\in C$ and for every partial assignment $p$, $f(p)\in C$.

My issue is what's the shape of $f(p)$. What I understand from the definition, is that first I need to see the class as set of boolean functions:

```
      000|001|010|011|100|101|110|111
  f1  0  |1  |1  |1  |0  | 0 | 0 | 0
  f2  1  |0  |0  |0  |1  | 0 | 0 | 0
  f3  1  |1  |0  |1  |0  | 0 | 0 | 0
```

(as |X|=5, three new elements were added and mapped to 0).

Then for $x\in X$ the projection of $x$ to $p$, $p(x)=(d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n)$ such that $d_i=p_i$ for all $p_i\in \{0,1\}$ and the $ith$ value in $x$ if $p_i=*$. For example, $x=(0,1,1)$ and $p=(1,*,0)$ will result in $(1,1,0)$.

It is assumed that most of the classes in the literature are projecton-closed.

Consider the concept $f_3$ and $p=001$, the projection $f_p$ is a new concept such that $f_p(x)=f_3(p(x))$ for every $x\in X$. As $p$ projects every $x$ to $001$ and $f_3(001)=1$ we have $f_p=\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\}$ . If my understanding is correct then any concept class where initially $|X|\neq 2^n$ will not be projection-closed. Is this true? I'm 99% sure I'm wrong but don't know where.